# Limit SSH max connections

Tags: 20.04, ssh

I have a server ( ubuntu 20.04 ) and need to limit max ssh active sessions (to decrease CPU usage ) ,i have added this

```
myuser   hard   maxlogins   1
```

to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

but it doesn't work! how can I limit this?

Thanks.

Comment: SSH connections do not require an appreciable amount of system resources. How does this reduce your server load? Are you sure this is the correct solution? 

Answer (score 2):

Very much inspired by [this article](https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/limit-simultaneous-connections):

Open the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in any text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the `MaxStartups` option and set the value to the maximum simultaneous connections to allow:

```
MaxStartups 1
```

From Manpage:

> **MaxStartups**
>  Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated
> connections to the SSH daemon. Additional connections will be dropped
> until authentication succeeds or the LoginGraceTime expires for a
> connection. The default is 10.
>
> Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the
> three colon separated values ''start:rate:full'' (e.g. "10:30:60").
> sshd(8) will refuse connection attempts with a probability of
> ''rate/100'' (30%) if there are currently ''start'' (10)
> unauthenticated connections. The probability increases linearly and
> all connection attempts are refused if the number of unauthenticated
> connections reaches ''full'' (60).

Find the `MaxSessions` option and set the value to the maximum simultaneous sessions to allow:

```
MaxSessions 1
```

From Manpage:

> **MaxSessions**
>  Specifies the maximum number of open sessions
> permitted per network connection. The default is 10.

Restart the `ssh` service (or its alias `sshd`):

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

This will allow one single connection attempt, as well as a single active session.

However as stated, it's questionable which effect this will have on CPU consumption.

Comment: Isn't it the daemon that needs restarting, sshd?

Comment: @pbhj `ssh` and `sshd` is the same service - it has an alias: `Alias=sshd.service`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , how can i limit for a user just ?

Comment: Your own solution with `/etc/security/limits.conf` should be the way to do it per user. I have no clue why that doesn't work for you.